# PHP intl not working when try to run from apache server

Tags: php, php-extension, codeigniter-4

I have a mac book with php. 7.3 version. I have installed php intl and when i run the following command in terminal it is working fine.

```
php -r "locale_set_default('de-DE'); echo locale_get_default();"
```

But same code if i run in php file it`s giving error Call to undefined function CodeIgniter\locale_set_default(). Could you please some one help me.

Comment: Read about [how namespaces work](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php).

Comment: Than you for the update. I read this but i an confuse where i need to change path to access that intl extension. Call to undefined function CodeIgniter\locale_set_default() this one is the CI error.